# #1067 - Valor predeterminado no válido para 'time'

Tags: mysql

**Cuando voy a phpMyAdmin para importar mi base de datos MySQL, aparece este error y se cancela la carga, Estoy usando la version 5.7.36 de MySQL.**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `freegen-history`
--

CREATE TABLE `freegen-history` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `DumpID` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `userid` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `username` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `DumpAlt` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `DumpCategory` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
   `time` time NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Aquí hay una captura de pantalla de lo que sale.**

[image: The part of the code that I don't know is the one that appears at the beginning of my publication]

**La parte del código que no se ve es la que aparece al principio de mi publicación, si alguien tiene la respuesta a esto por favor que me la diga.**

Comment: Hola! Estás en SOes, así que todo debe ir en español. Por favor ve a [edit]

Comment: Listo ya lo hice y gracias por la modificacion que hiciste.

Comment: El valor default es incorrecto para el tipo de datos TIME. Cambia `current_timestamp()` por `CURRENT_TIME` o [CURTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time)

Comment: Cuando realice los cambios e intente importa mi base de datos obtuve un nuevo error https://prnt.sc/c4QpVzI6AAta 

Cambio realizado : https://prnt.sc/yHmZIR5nN1kq

Comment: ¿Qué versión exacta de MySQL Server está usando?. Desde MySQL Server 8.0.13, tendrá que cambiar `... \`time\` time NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ...` a `... \`time\` time NOT NULL DEFAULT (current_timestamp()) ...`. También podrá usar `... \`time\` time NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURTIME()) ...`.

Comment: Estoy usando la version 5.7.36 aqui te dejare una img del error nuevo : https://prnt.sc/QY0OYNFQlZxC y del cambio que realice : https://prnt.sc/bGi0Vq6tpBjx hice ambas cosas que dijiste pero daban error.

Comment: La versión de MySQL Server 5.7.36 no soporta la sintaxis mencionada [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/550957/1067-valor-predeterminado-no-v%c3%a1lido-para-time#comment974492_550957).

Answer (score 1):

El problema en tu código es debido **al tipo de dato que estás indicando (`time`) el cual no soporta el tipo de valor por defecto que intentas asignarle: `current_timestamp()`**.

Si lo defines así funcionaría:

```
`time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
```

De todos modos, estas dos columnas van a asumir el mismo valor:

```
`date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
`time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
```

Con que definas una sola columna basta, definir dos sería **redundancia de datos**.

Finalmente, evita usar palabras reservadas para definir tus columnas.

Este sería el código final que te recomiendo implementar:

```
CREATE TABLE `freegen-history` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `DumpID` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `userid` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `username` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `DumpAlt` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `DumpCategory` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `current_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: A.Cedano: No olvide cambiar, en la sentencia `CREATE TABLE`, el tipo de dato de la columna `current_ts` (`DATETIME` o `TIMESTAMP`).

Comment: @wchiquito gracias por señalarlo, se me escapó ese detalle. Ya está corregido.